# How to compress image asset from multi_image_picker flutter?

Tags: flutter, image-compression

Libraries used: https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress

I am using multi image picker lib to get multiple images from the gallery. However, before uploading them I want to compress image's size first.

Multiple image picker return `List<Asset>` but in flutter_image_compress lib, we can only compress image as a type of File like this:

```
Future<Uint8List> testCompressFile(File file) async {
    var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(
      file.absolute.path,
      minWidth: 2300,
      minHeight: 1500,
      quality: 94,
      rotate: 90,
    );
    return result;
  }
```

How can I convert `List<Asset>` to `List<File>` in order to compress image?

Comment: https://github.com/Sh1d0w/multi_image_picker/issues/605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. Please check my full source code here: https://soksereyphon8.medium.com/upload-multiple-images-and-compress-image-in-flutter-62d113a3247a

Answer (score 0):

You can get the images in a list of type Uint8List and use this flutter package [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress) compress them like this

For images in a list of type Uint8List

```
  Future<List<Uint8List>> compressImages(List<Uint8List>? imageBytesList) async {
    List<Uint8List>? compressedImageList = [];

    for (Uint8List image in imageBytesList!) {
      var compressedImageData = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
        image,
        minHeight: 1920,
        minWidth: 1080,
        quality: 60,
      );
      compressedImageList.add(compressedImageData);
    }

    return compressedImageList;
  }
```

Specify image and height as you wish.

For images in a list of type Uint8List

```
Future<List<File>> compressImages(List<Asset>? imageAssets, String targetDirectory) async {
  List<File> compressedImageList = [];

  for (Asset imageAsset in imageAssets!) {
    ByteData byteData = await imageAsset.getByteData();
    List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    String targetPath = '$targetDirectory/${imageAsset.name}';
    var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
      imageData,
      targetPath,
      quality: 88,
      rotate: 180,
    );

    compressedImageList.add(result);
  }

  return compressedImageList;
}
```